# Include/require not working - online payment script

Tags: php, wordpress, mailing, payu

I have very weird problem:
I've created simple Wordpress based store. I sell e-books and send them via email. I use online payments and have plugin to work with them. It have build-in gateway in php file. I want to inject my code to this script to automatize selling. It looks like this:

```
<?php
//1. Get payment info from payment service via $_POST
//2. Chceck all hashes etc.
//3. Get status to variable e.g. $status
if ($status == 99)//everything is ok
{
    $order_id = $_POST["no_of_transaction"];
    log_to_file("Yeah i am workig. id =".$order_id."with status ".$status);
    include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/sell_stuff.php";
    log_to_file("Yeah i am still workig");
}
?>
```

sell_stuff.php:

```
<?php
log_to_file("Hello i am in sending script!");
//i assume that $order_id is still visible
$order = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM order where id=".$order_id));
$mail->to = $order['email'];
$mail->attachment = "/upload/pdf/".$order['book'].'.pdf';
$mail->send();
?>
```

And this method not working at all :( I've tried to change include to require and use ABSPATH instead of $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] but it still fails. Last thing logged in log file is ""Yeah i am workig. id= xxx with status = 99".
I've created test.php file like this:

```
<?php
echo "Yeah i am workig";
$oder_id = 100; //my own order
include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/sell_stuff.php";
echo "Yeah i am still workig";
?>
```

... and when I run this via www.mystore.com/test.php it's work perfectly. It logging to file "Hello i am in sending script!" and all other stuff.
I dont know where i make mistake :(

Comment: Before the include try (for debugging purposes)  `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);`. Anything pops up?

Comment: You should not rely on $_SERVER variable but instead on the location of the calling script. Something like this : `include __DIR__ . '/../inc/sell_stuff.php' `

Answer (score 0):

Try to drop "/", and use it like:

```
$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."sell_stuff.php";
```

Also $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] is genereating path to you www root folder, like

```
www.serwer.com/www/
```

If u have your site in:

```
www.serwer.com/www/www2/
```

it will not get included. If u will use:

```
__DIR__."/sell_stuff.php";
```

it will get the path to place where your file is.

```
www.serwer.com/www/www2/
```

You can always:

```
var_dump($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
var_dump(__DIR__);
```

to see the difference and the path that you are getting.

Comment: `var_dump($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
var_dump(__DIR__);` are the same

Comment: Try to move your file lever deeper. If your main root is www.site.www/www/, then move it to www.site.www/www/www2/ and then check with above.

Comment: Yep __dir__ shows current folder and $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] still main folder but in my case is irrevelant becaouse sell_stuff.php is in main folder :/